# Adding the CSS for successive rows when they are added

Tags: css

*Here I am trying to add rounded corners. As of now only two rows are getting effected for rounded corners. Please help in adding rounded corners to all the rows when they are being added using the add row button.*

```
<html lang="en">
        <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <title>Expenses</title>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
          <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
          <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
          <style type="text/css">
         table.expense {
            width: 800px;
            -moz-border-radius: 20px;
            border-radius: 20px;
            border-color:#009900;}
            td.a {
            width: 800px;
            -moz-border-radius: 20px;
            border-radius: 20px;
         }
         td.b {
            width: 800px;
            -moz-border-radius: 20px;
            border-radius: 20px;
         }
         td.c {
            width: 800px;
            -moz-border-radius: 20px;
            border-radius: 20px;
         }
         td.d {
            width: 800px;
            -moz-border-radius: 20px;
            border-radius: 20px;
         }
            </style>


          <script>

function addRow(tableID) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
    var counts = rowCount - 1;

    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var expense_date = document.createElement("input");
    expense_date.type = "text";
    expense_date.name = "expenses[" + counts + "].expense_date";
    cell1.appendChild(expense_date);
    $('input[name="' + expense_date.name + '"]').datepicker();
    //add this line.


    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var expense_against = document.createElement("input");
    expense_against.type = "text";
    expense_against.name = "expenses[" + counts + "].expense_against";
    cell2.appendChild(expense_against);

    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var amount = document.createElement("input");
    amount.type = "text";
    amount.name = "expenses[" + counts + "].amount";
    cell3.appendChild(amount);

    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
    var paid_by = document.createElement("input");
    paid_by.type = "text";
    paid_by.name = "expenses[" + counts + "].paid_by";
    cell4.appendChild(paid_by);

}
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();

  });
</script>
</head>


<body>
         <form action="submit" method="post">

        <p align ="center"><font size = "6" face = "Cursive">Expenses</font></p>

        <TABLE class = "expense" id="expensesTable" border = "4" align="center">
                <TR>
                        <TD class = "a" align = "center"><font size = "4" face = "Cursive">EXPENSE_DATE</font></TD>
                        <TD class = "b" align = "center"><font size = "4" face = "Cursive">EXPENSE_AGAINST</font></TD>
                        <TD class = "c" align = "center"><font size = "4" face = "Cursive">AMOUNT</font></TD>
                        <TD class = "d" align = "center"><font size = "4" face = "Cursive">PAID_BY</font></TD>
                </TR>
                <TR>
                        <TD class = "a"><INPUT type="text" id="datepicker" name="expenses[0].expense_date" /></TD>
                        <TD class = "b"><INPUT type="text" name="expenses[0].expense_against" /></TD>
                        <TD class = "c"><INPUT type="text" name="expenses[0].amount" /></TD>
                        <TD class = "d"><INPUT type="text" name="expenses[0].paid_by" /></TD>

                </TR>
        </TABLE> 


        <p align ="center">
        <INPUT type="button" value="Add More" name="expenses[0].more" onclick="addRow('expensesTable')" />
        <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" />
        </p>
        </form>



        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle with your current result?

Comment: In jsfiddle the above code looks messed up if it is okay to provide a screen shot of the output if that's what you want...

Comment: @codegaze the code didnt work out the way it should in jsfiddle ..... here is the link https://jsfiddle.net/u8zmugyr/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the "addRow" function is not setting the new cel's classes, adding

```
cell1.setAttribute("class", "a");
cell2.setAttribute("class", "b");
cell3.setAttribute("class", "c");
cell4.setAttribute("class", "d");
```

to the end of it will fix it

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/08rr7oy7/)